# How would I know if $f(x)=x^5-2x+10$ has a root at the interval $[-2, 2]$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Unsure on the procedure on this one and then how to explain it.  I don't think this function has any rational roots, right?

Comment: It depends on what you're allowed to use. If you evaluate $f(-2)$ and $f(2)$, what do you get? If you're allowed something like the [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) and you know that polynomials are continuous, then these two values get you what you want. At the level of precalculus I don't know offhand.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$f(-2) = (-2)^5 -2(-2) + 10 = -32 + 4 + 10 = -18 < 0$$
while
$$f(2) = 2^5 - 2(2) + 10 = 38 > 0.$$

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Sturm's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) and [Descartes's Rule of Signs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs).

Answer (score 3):

As I understand, you actually have *three* questions:

- Does $f(x)=x^5-2x+10$ has **zeros** on the interval $[-2,2]$? (Notice that you can either say the **root** of $f(x)=0$ or **zeros** of $f(x)$. I don't think people would say "the root of $f(x)$".)
- How to prove the existence of non-existence above?
- If the root of $f(x)=0$ exists, is it rational?

Here are my answers:

- First, try it on Mathematica. You can see the answer from the picture.

[image]

- For the proof, as mentioned in the comments by other users, do you know [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)?
- For the third question, see [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: Intermediate value theorem, not mean value theorem, surely?

Comment: I think saying "roots of polynomials" is very common, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate $f(2)$ and $f(-2)$. In your case they are 38 and -18 respectively. Since $f(x)$ changes its sign as one decreases $x$ from 2 to -2, $f(x)$ must have crossed the $f(x)=0$ line at some $x$. This proves that $f(x)$ has a root somewhere in the interval $[-2,2]$.

PS : Given the fact that $f(x)$ is continuous. See a comment below.

Comment: @Dilawar When using this argument, you must remember to mention that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. Thanks! Sorry for leaving a gap!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a polinomial has rational roots, you use the Rational Roots Theorem. For a polynomial 
$$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$$
All rational roots must be of the form 
$$\pm \frac{p}{q}$$
where $p$ is a factor of $a_0$ and $q$ is a factor of $a_n$. No other rational roots may exist. In this case, you have $p=\{1,2,5,10\}$ and $q=1$, so your possible rational roots are $\{\pm1,\pm2,\pm5,\pm10\}$. If you evaluate the function at these points (don't do it by hand), you'll see none of them equal zero, so your function has no rational roots.